# Get pixel color in background on Android

Tags: android, android-service

I need to create a service that keeps checking a coordinate of an android screen for the color of a pixel.

Eg.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getBackground()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);

if(pixel == Color.MAGENTA){
   //Stop Service
}
```

However instead of just my app, I need it to be in a background service which keeps checking for the color even when I switch apps.

Assuming the device is rooted, is there any superuser commands that does what I need?

Comment: This sounds horribly inefficient and cumbersome. Why not explore other options?

Comment: use broadcast reciever in your service and send broadcast from your activity, and subscribe to the broadcast in your service

Comment: What is the aim here? What are you trying to check? You want to know when for example a magenta pixel is displayed at x, y position on the screen from any app (eg Facebook)? The answers are all looking at things rendered only within your app so you need to be clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To those who need to do something like I am doing,

I used the system's command /system/bin/screencap -p to capture the screen and check for the pixel on the screenshot.

This method requires the root permission

```
private void getPixelColor(int xcoord, int ycoord)
{
    try {
        Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

        OutputStream os = sh.getOutputStream();
        os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/colorPickerTemp.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
        os.flush();

        os.close();
        sh.waitFor();

        Bitmap screen = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "colorPickerTemp.png");
        int pixel = screen.getPixel(xcoord ,ycoord + statusHeight);
        Log.d("pixel color", "Pixel Color: + " + Integer.toHexString(pixel) + " at x:" + xcoord + " y:" + ycoord);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Found a better way to go about this ? Screencap is kinda slow

Answer (score 3):

```
public class TouchView extends ImageView {

 Bitmap bitmap;
 double bmWidth, bmHeight; 

 public TouchView(Context context) {
  super(context);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
  super(context, attrs);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 public TouchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
  super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  init();
 }

 private void init(){

  bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)getBackground()).getBitmap();
  bmWidth = (double)bitmap.getWidth();
  bmHeight = (double)bitmap.getHeight();
 }

 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
       MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub


  switch(event.getAction()){
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
   float x = event.getX();
   float y = event.getY();

   int color = getColor(x, y);
      ((AndroidDetechTouchActivity)getContext()).updateMsg("Touched@" + x + " : " + y, color);

   break;
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
   ((AndroidDetechTouchActivity)getContext()).updateMsg("", 0);
   break;
  }

  return true;
 }

 private int getColor(float x, float y){

  if ( x < 0 || y < 0 || x > (float)getWidth() || y > (float)getHeight()){
   return 0; //Invalid, return 0
  }else{
   //Convert touched x, y on View to on Bitmap
   int xBm = (int)(x * (bmWidth / (double)getWidth()));
      int yBm = (int)(y * (bmHeight / (double)getHeight()));

   return bitmap.getPixel(xBm, yBm);
  }

 }

}
```

Modify updateMsg() method of main activity, AndroidDetechTouchActivity.java, to include color and update TextView's TextColor.

```
public class AndroidDetechTouchActivity extends Activity {

 TextView msg;
 TouchView touchView;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        msg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.msg);
        touchView = (TouchView)findViewById(R.id.touchview);

    }

    public void updateMsg(String tMsg, int color){
     msg.setTextColor(color);
     msg.setText(tMsg);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply and this great code, however does this gets the pixel color of other apps too?

Answer (score 0):

you can draw to bitmap and take color from bitmap, code as follow:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), 
view.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
view.draw(c);
int color = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
```

Answer (score -1):

As stated. inefficient in general... probably a better way for you to implement your application.

```
 public boolean checkColor() {
       View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
       rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
       Bitmap bitmap = rootView.getDrawingCache();
       rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
       int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
       if(pixel == Color.MAGENTA){
           return true;
       }
       return false;
    }
```

Comment: Needs to be done from a background service though. This only works in-app.